# "Review" tab is missing in Experience Editor but appears in Content Editor

Tags: experience-editor, ribbon

Both on my local and in upstream environments, the "Review" tab is missing in the Experience Editor (even when I'm signed in as an admin):

[image]

However, the Content Editor does show the "Review" tab:

[image]

This is a problem because users cannot submit items to be approved when they are working in the Experience Editor.

I'm using Sitecore.NET 9.0.2 (rev. 180604).

How can I enable the "Review" tab in the Experience Editor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Experience Editor does not *have* a "Review" tab. Items that have workflow applied will display the work flow options at the top of the page in a blue bar as in the screenshot below:

[image]

Please see the workflow documentation for further clarification: https://doc.sitecore.com/users/90/sitecore-experience-platform/en/move-an-item-to-the-next-workflow-state.html

Comment: Perfect. Now the question is why Sitecore made this decision...